# Euler's method to approximate a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = x - y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, eulers-method

**Question:** Use Euler's method to find approximate values for the solution of the initial value $-$ problem

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x-y$$
$$y(0)=1$$
on the interval $[0,1]$ using five steps of size $h = 0.2$.

**My attempts:**

> I know that the recurrence relation $y_{n+1} = y_{n} + hf(x_n,y_n)$ however I am unable to see how the interval comes into play.
> An idea I had was to consider the bounds of the interval and approximate $y(0)$ and $y(1)$ however this does not include $h$ so I am extremely skeptical.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not answering the question, but once you obtain your approximation, you probably should try to compare it with the exact solution $$y(x)=x-1+2\,\exp(-x)\,.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a little table -- I've filled in the first couple of rows for you:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & y & \Delta x & \frac{dy}{dx} = x - y & \Delta y \approx \frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0.2 & -1 & -0.2 \\
\hline
0.2 & 0.8 & 0.2 & -0.6 &-0.12  \\
\hline
0.4 & 0.68 & 0.2 & & \\
\hline
0.6 & &0.2 & & \\
\hline
0.8 & &0.2 & & \\ 
\hline
1 & & 0.2 & & \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

You are done when you get to the bottom left.

Comment: I always recommend tables for Euler’s method. Most people don’t use it, and I can’t understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You compute step-by-step approximations of $y(0.2)$, $y(0.4)$, $y(0.6)$, $y(0.8)$ and then $y(1.0)$. Or in other words, $x_n=x_0+n\cdot h$ and $y_n$ is the approximation of $y(x_n)$.